# Create Textbox widgets in Tkinter of different length for multiple Labels in different rows

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox

I have been trying to create an application using Tkinter module for Python 3.4.2 
There are N number of labels. 
For each of these N number of labels, I am trying to create a row of Textboxes which **might/might not** be of the same length. 
The number of Textboxes for each label might be different too. 
I need a scrollbar for this window.
So I created a canvas and used Scrollbar widget to create the horizontal and vertical scrollbar. In this canvas, I entered a frame so that I could add my labels and Textboxes. 
To construct Textboxes of varying lengths I used grid() method for the widgets. 
*I read that the grid columns are of length enough to accommodate the largest widget(here it is a Textbox) and you can't add multiple widgets in a cell of the grid.*

I used columnspan property of the Textbox widget but was of no help. **e1.grid(row=i, column=1, columnspan=width)**
for the first column 
and **e1.grid(row=i, column=width_sum, columnspan=width)** for the subsequent columns. Here width_sum is the sum of length of different textboxes because of the present one. The width_sum parameter is reset for every Label (which is present in a different row).

I need output something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seVEB.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To realize the GUI you describe, I think your best option is to:

- Create 1 frame per row.
- Then in each frame, use the `.pack()` geometry manager to pack the textboxes side by side.

[image]

**Code**:

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint

root = tk.Tk()

# Create N frames on top of each other
N = 4 
frames = []
for n in range(N):
    frame = tk.Frame(root)
    frame.pack(side='top', anchor='w')
    # Store the current frame reference in "frames"
    frames.append(frame)

# Add some widgets in each frame
entryboxes = {frame: [] for frame in frames}
for i, frame in enumerate(frames):
    # Add a label
    label = tk.Label(frame, text="Label "+str(i+1))
    label.pack(side='left')
    # Add 5 Entry boxes with random widths
    for i in range(5):
        random_width = 10 + randint(0,9)
        e = tk.Entry(frame, width = random_width)
        e.pack(side='left')
        # Store the current entrybox reference in "entryboxes"
        entryboxes[frame].append(e)

# Add some text in the 4th box of the 3rd frame
entryboxes[frames[2]][3].insert(0, 'hello')

# Launch the app
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hey Josselin, thanks for the reply. Adding a frame for each row seems to be the natural solution now.

Comment: Glad you like it! You can accept the answer if it fixed your problem ;) http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers